# sbt project for spark , but not found some package in context?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

i try to build a new project use sbt in IDEA Intellj .

create project and add Dependency library is sucess .

build.sbt content:

```
name := "spark-hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.4.1"
```

main code:
[image]

as above pictures, the red section is error, I think it is strange, such as:

toInt method should be built-in function, but this not found it.

I don't know why solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` in IntelliJ's menu.

Answer (score 1):

Change your library dependency to :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "1.4.1"
```

or

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.4.1"
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer!  but some package   Still can't import  toInt , until , print and so on  keyword is not found in this context ! loking forward your reply

Comment: did you reload the SBT? (from SBT window)

Comment: yes ,  i have already reload dependency  , but some keywords ( print , until , toInt) still not found  in context  .

Comment: is there any main function or any function there?

Comment: only one main function

Comment: i have already udpate above problems , you can look some error in it !

Comment: I tested gain here, it's working for me, close-open IntelliJ, where is your file located?

Comment: hi ,  my question had already settled ， thanks for you again　！